# Install Anaconda in Ubuntu Docker

Tags: ubuntu, python, docker

I have installed [anaconda](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-16-04) in Docker Ubuntu 16.04LTS

```
RUN \
    curl -O https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    yes "yes" | bash Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    sudo -s source ~/.bashrc
```

but when I do

```
RUN conda list
```

I get a `/bin/sh: 1: conda: not found` error.

According to `anaconda` install `In order to activate the installation, you should source the ~/.bashrc file:`, but it seems this did not work in this case.

Comment: can you please report the content of your .bashrc file just use cat ~/.bashrc

Comment: So that's it: `export PATH="/root/yes/bin:$PATH"`. I do not see why it is in the `yes/` folder. The `which` conda says `/root/yes/bin/conda`. I do not understand why it's in the `yes` command folder actually. If I login in the `docker` container `conda` works. In the `Dockerfile` it does not.

Comment: I have changed then in this way `/root/yes/bin/conda list` to make it working.  The problem seems to be the `yes` script then...